# How to pass in a list of elements individually to a function call?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, struct, databricks

I am trying to utilize the Databricks [struct() function](https://docs.databricks.com/sql/language-manual/functions/struct.html) and it takes in columns individually like struct(c1, c2, c3). But I would like to pass in a list of columns to the function or achieve similar results by some other method.

```
val keyList = List("key1", "key2")

df
.select(
  struct(keyList).as("key")
...
```

My Dataframe contains columns key1, key2 and I want to contain them together in a struct(). I thought I could use something like keyList:_* but apparently the function is not *-parameterized. Any advice on how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TLDR, use this:

```
df
.select(struct(keyList.map(col(_)): _*).as("key"))) ..
```

From [Docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions$.html) the defintions are:

```
def struct(colName: String, colNames: String*): Column
```

and

```
def struct(cols: Column*): Column
```

We can pass list to the varargs (arguments with *) using the unpack operator: `_*`

Thus, for the first function that accepts string, we'll need one argument to be string, and second can be varargs. For the later, we can pass List of Columns.

These both should work:

```
df.select(struct("id", df.columns.filterNot(_.startsWith("id")): _*)).show()

df.select(struct(df.columns.map(col(_)): _*)).show()
```

Input:

```
+---+----------+-----+
| id|         A|value|
+---+----------+-----+
|  a|    vowels|    1|
|  b|consonants|    2|
|  c|consonants|    3|
|  d|consonants|    4|
|  e|    vowels|    5|
+---+----------+-----+
```

Output:

```
+--------------------+
|struct(id, A, value)|
+--------------------+
|      {a, vowels, 1}|
|  {b, consonants, 2}|
|  {c, consonants, 3}|
|  {d, consonants, 4}|
|      {e, vowels, 5}|
+--------------------+
```